# Wordpress plugin service page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

have spent hours of researching understanding the correct approach for developing plugin for wordpress which does have custom "service" URL.

So far done:

- plugin registers custom capabilities and role
- inits the db and entries using $wpdb
- create rest-api hook that could be used with JS

Should do:

- Only the users with custom role "service" shall have access to a service dashboard.
- the service dashboard shall make use of $wpdb to query data from the db.

I am looking badly for a simple example to learn from which shows a custom page that isn't integrated into WP posts or the admin panel.

Something that does check current user and allow access for given role to e.g. "www.awesome-wp-page.com/myplugin/main" and load some further data later as e.g. "www.awesome-wp-page.com/myplugin/stats/1234"

Originally I wanted WP to query the data via its own custom restapi, but also did not find any examples that query rest-api within WP (providing nonce etc) as simple example.

I found a lot examples for admin panels, adding links to post etc, but to my surprise not really some examples which do load simple (form) page or do a quick custom DB query and show the results on a static link.

Any help is appreciated